# Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reactjs

When I load my react app I get this error in the console.

> Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form
>   field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only
>   field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise,
>   set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of
>   `AppFrame`.

My AppFrame component is below:

```
class AppFrame extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <header className="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-shadow">
                    <div className="navbar-branding">
                        <a className="navbar-brand" href="dashboard">
                            <b>Shire</b>Soldiers
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <form className="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-search alt" role="search">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search..."
                                   value="Search..."/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li className="dropdown menu-merge">
                            <span className="caret caret-tp hidden-xs"></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </header>

                <aside id="sidebar_left" className="nano nano-light affix">

                    <div className="sidebar-left-content nano-content">

                        <ul className="nav sidebar-menu">
                            <li className="sidebar-label pt20">Menu</li>
                            <li className="sidebar-label">
                                <IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Dashboard</IndexLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="sidebar-label">
                                <Link to="/fixtures" activeClassName="active">Fixtures</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="sidebar-label">
                                <Link to="/players" activeClassName="active">Players</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </aside>
                <section id="content_wrapper">
                    <section id="content" className="table-layout animated fadeIn">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </section>
                </section>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default AppFrame;
```

I am struggling to work out what I am actually doing wrong here. The application starts up and works but I am trying to remove all console warning/errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Try this,

```
const [email, SetEmail] = useState("");
```

```
<Form.Control
    onChange={e => SetEmail(e.target.value)}
    type="email"
    name="email"
    value={email || ""}
/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 187):

You've put a value directly in your search input, I don't see the benefit there because you already have a placeholder. You could either remove the value from:

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search..." value="Search..."/>
```

to this:

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search..." />
```

Or if you think you must have it, set it as `defaultValue`:

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search..." defaultValue="Search..."/>
```

Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: Has anyone gotten this error with a submit button, though? That doesn't make sense to me. For `input type="submit"`, `value` is expected to provide the text. Why would this error show in this case?

Comment: @MartavisP. not sure, but you could use `<button type="submit>Your value in here</button>` instead.

Comment: I'm ashamed. I had actually messed up my code to get that message. Everything is ffffiiiinnnneeee :-)

Comment: For me it doesn't work, and I don't understand why, I see already many and many post and I have always the same error with the fact that I can't write in my input

Comment: @Tryliom could you create a jsfiddle or something to reproduce your error?

Answer (score 35):

If you don't take the input value from the user by this input field, then you need to make this field read-only by setting the **defaultValue**.

In case if you want to set the value and involve user interaction. You should send **onChange** event to update the state of initial value. This is like two-way binding as angular support.

```
state = {
   keyword: 'test' 
} 

inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
    const updatedKeyword = event.target.value;
    // May be call for search result
}

render() {
  return (
      <input 
         type="text" 
         placeholder="Search..."
         value={this.state.keyword} 
         onChange={(event)=>this.inputChangedHandler(event)} />
   );
}
```

Comment: How does setting updatedKeyword in the change handler change what is displayed in the input field?

Comment: @DanMeigs That line doesn't do anything. You can literally just have an empty onChange handler method and it will work fine.

Comment: I'm sure they have their reasons for designing it like that, but it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 4):

the warning appears because you set a value attribute on the input and don't provide any handler to update it. there is two way to do so:

1. you can use a **ref** to get form values from the DOM.

   https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html
2. set **onChange** handler function.

Answer (score 1):

1.**This is for use only functional component!**
**2.**you should replace **value** to **defaultvalue** or you should set **onChangeHandler** in inside of input field.

**3.**This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use **`defaultValue`**. Otherwise, set either **`onChange`** or `readOnly`.

```js
const [state,setState]=useState('');
return(<>
<input
type='text'
defaultValue={state}
onChange={(e)=>setState(e.target.value)}
placeholder='UserName'
name='username'
/>
</>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you have to see the submitted type. If you don't give a type you will face an error.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className='grid grid-cols-1 gap-3 justify-items- 
      center mt-3'>
     <input type="text" disabled value={format(date, 'PP')} 
                     className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
     <select name='slot' class="select select-bordered w-full max- 
     w-xs">
        {
            slots.map(slot => <option value={slot}>{slot} 
            </option>)
        }
     </select>
     <input type="text" name='name' placeholder="Your Name" 
     className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
     <input type="email" name='email' placeholder="Email Address" 
     className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
     <input type="text" name='phone' placeholder="Phone Number" 
     className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn- 
     secondary text-white font-semibold w-full max-w-xs" />
</form>
```