# onChange function doesn't work for input while using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am writing a simple code which will produce an input box with data. As I change the data in the input box, the database should be updated. I am using an onChange function will trigger an action to achieve this, but the onChange doesn't seem to fire at all. The browser keeps showing "Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form..".

The following is my code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {handleChange} from '../actions/handleChange';


class NoteSelected extends Component {
   render() {   // onChange to be added
        const inputStyle = {width: "100%"};
        if(!this.props.noteSelected)
            return (<h4>Select a note..</h4>)
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-9 col-md-6 col-lg-8" >
            <h4>{this.props.noteSelected.heading}</h4>
            <input key={this.props.noteSelected.id} id={this.props.noteSelected.id} 
             value={this.props.noteSelected.text} onChange={this.props.handleChange} style={inputStyle} />
        </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        noteSelected: state.noteSelected
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({handleChange: handleChange}, dispatch)
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (NoteSelected);
```

Comment: Gone here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556212/failed-form-proptype-you-provided-a-value-prop-to-a-form-field-without-an-on

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to solve the issue even though I change the 'value' to 'placeholder' or 'defaultValue'.

Comment: what error is shown when you change to `defaultValue` ?

Comment: The same error. When I see in the react-devtools chrome extension, it says that the props given to `input` is read only and doesn't even show the `onChange` function inside input field.

Comment: how can the same error show up if you don't have a `value` prop in your input ? I asked you to change your component so: `<input id={this.props.noteSelected.id} defaultValue={this.props.noteSelected.text} onChange={this.props.handleChange} style={inputStyle} />` **P.S.** provide the `key` prop to only components inside an array

Comment: Can you please include your action creator and reducer (at least the applicable parts)?

Comment: I am sorry @Dane, changing `value` to `defaultValue` has worked. I misinformed you because there was a problem while updating the webpack server and the changes I made weren't reflecting. I resolved it now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed form propType: You provided a \`value\` prop to a form field without an \`onChange\` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556212/failed-form-proptype-you-provided-a-value-prop-to-a-form-field-without-an-on)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is actually the same as in this link: [Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556212/failed-form-proptype-you-provided-a-value-prop-to-a-form-field-without-an-on)

Simply changing the `value` to `defaultValue` or `placeholder` has solved the issue.