# Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field. React-Bootstrap-Typehead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am using the bootstrap-typehead:https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead and I cannot figure out why this package is freaking out. Whats wrong with this code that it gives me this error:

Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Dropdown from "../../bootstrap/Dropdown";
import RealmAPIs from "../../../API/realms/RealmAPI";

import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';

import AutoComplete from "../../bootstrap/AutoComplete";
// import RealmAPI from '../../../API/realms/RealmAPI';

var options = [
  'John',
  'Miles',
  'Charles',
  'Herbie',
];

export default class FindCharacter extends Component {
  state = {
    realmName: "",
    characterName: "",
    realms: []
  };



  setRealmName = value => {
    this.setState({ realmName: value });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // let realms = [...this.state.realms];
    // RealmAPIs.getAllRealms().then(response =>
    //   console.log(response.realms.map(value => {}))
    // );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="form-inline justify-content-md-center">
          <div className="form-group mb-2">
            {/* <Dropdown setRealmName={this.setRealmName}/> */}
            <Typeahead
              labelKey="name"
            placeholder="Type a realm"
              onChange={selected => {
                console.log(selected);
              }}
              options={
                options
              }
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="characterName"
              placeholder="Enter Character Name"
            />
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-primary mb-2"
            onClick={e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log(this.state.name);
            }}
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43556671/2630817

Comment: Hey so i actually saw this but I tried throwing in an onchange to my input filed, I tried onChange, im not sure how to apply it to my current situation.

Comment: You should have one local state, every onchange is subject to change the state, and rerender the input. so, you will have the updated state with input changes every time

Comment: So typehead has the Onchange in it. So when I remove typehead from the render the warning goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to v3.2.3 of react-bootstrap-typeahead should solve the issue.

I'm not sure why, but React v16.5 (I think?) started triggering the warning. There was [an issue tracking it](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/issues/381) as well as [a PR fixing it](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/pull/376).